# Websphere v6.1 - Destination Queue was not found on messaging engine

Tags: java, queue, jms, websphere

I am new to `JMS`, was trying below sample `jms` application. I have created queue connection factory ("jms/sampleQFactory") and provider queue ("jms/sampleQFactory") in the `websphere` console. I have created & linked System Integration Bus (SIB) "sampleBus" with Queue connection factory. Exception is thrown while creating sender queue.

***QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);***

```
    public void send(){
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/sampleQFactory");

        Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("q/sampleSendingQ");

        ctx.close();

        QueueConnection connection = factory.createQueueConnection();

        QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Sending Message --- " + MESSAGE);
        sender.send(message);

        connection.close();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting below error:

```
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.exceptions.SIMPNotPossibleInCurrentConfigurationException: CWSIK0015E: The destination sampleSendingQ was not found on messaging engine SB02861Node01.server1-SampleBus.
at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.DestinationManager.checkDestinationHandlerExists(DestinationManager.java:3855)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.DestinationManager.getDestination(DestinationManager.java:966)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.ConnectionImpl.internalCreateProducerSession(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.ConnectionImpl.createProducerSession(ConnectionImpl.java:868)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsMsgProducerImpl.<init>(JmsMsgProducerImpl.java:385)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueSenderImpl.<init>(JmsQueueSenderImpl.java:75)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueSessionImpl.instantiateProducer(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:361)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1101)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueSessionImpl.createSender(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:236)
at net.viralpatel.spring3.messaging.MessageProducer.send(MessageProducer.java:31)
at net.viralpatel.spring3.controller.HelloWorldController.processRequest(HelloWorldController.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1103)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:570)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:486)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:748)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)

[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.DestinationManager.checkDestinationHandlerExists(DestinationManager.java:3855)
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.DestinationManager.getDestination(DestinationManager.java:966)
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.ConnectionImpl.internalCreateProducerSession(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.impl.ConnectionImpl.createProducerSession(ConnectionImpl.java:868)
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsMsgProducerImpl.<init>(JmsMsgProducerImpl.java:385)
[6/11/14 9:02:34:435 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R  ... 39 more
```

Please help.

Comment: It looks like your destination queue on wrong server SB02861Node01.server1-SampleBus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the queue on the bus:

CWSIK0015E: The destination sampleSendingQ was not found on messaging engine SB02861Node01.server1-SampleBus

In the admin console go to: Service Integration > Buses > myBus

- In the `Bus Members` section check, if your server is added to the bus (if not add it)
- In the `Destinations` section, click 'New' to define queue on the bus (sampleSendingQ)
- In the `Resources > JMS > Queues` select your defined queue - you should be able to select correct bus and created queue (if not, create jms queue again)
- Save changes and restart the server

You should be fine then.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using same names for messaging queues and queue connection factories that could be the reason. because the service integration technologies always look first for JMS destinations locally, and only use the full JNDI reference if they cannot find the destination locally.